# При изменении пути @GetMapping не отрабатывает

Tags: java, веб-программирование, spring-mvc

При

```
 @GetMapping("/")
 public String view() {
 return "index";
 }
```

[image: работает]

всё работает.
Когда меняешь маршрут

```
@GetMapping("/view")
public String view() {
    return "index";
}
```

перестаёт работать.
[image: ошибка]
Через @RequestMapping ситуация аналогичная.
Меняла настройки, код. Уже не знаю, что ещё делать.

Comment: после изменения "маршрута" проект пересобирала, заново диплоила?

Comment: Вас не смущает, что при / у вас отображается 12, а не **index** ( как у вас в коде написано) ? Ну и скорее всего у вас по / находится другой маппинг, и то, что вы тут меняете - никак не применяется. Приложите код контроллера всего ( а точнее аннотацию, которая висит на этом контроллере)

Comment: Я делала по этому видеоуроку https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CKR4pmXntjw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я пропустила / в пути, из-за этого была проблема. Спасибо всем кто пытался помочь.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Внутри url-pattern был пропущен слеш, глупая ошибка, 3 дня её искала

Comment: Где именно был пропущен `/`? Стоит добавить в ответ соответствующий кусок кода.

Answer (score 0):

потому что ваш файл index.htm находится в корневой папке проекта тоесть по пути "/", а по пути "/view" у вас нету файла  index.htm.Если вы хотите что бы файл был по пути "/view" то переместите туда файл index.htm или создайте новый файл html